# SQL Optimize Approach

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a newbie question regarding optimizing this query

Assuming I have 3 tables.
Student, Class and Group

Assuming I have trillions of data/records, what's the optimal way for this query?
Should I just create an Indexes for each column I've used? Create a temporary table first instead of sub query? Thanks!

```
SELECT  Student_ID,
    BDate,
    SUM(Calc1 + Calc2 ) / 2 AS Calc4
        FROM (
            SELECT a.student_id AS Student_ID, a.birthday AS BDate, 
        SUM(a.test1 + a.test2 / a.test3) AS Calc1,
        SUM(a.test1 + a.test2 + a.test3) AS Calc2,
        AVG(b.test1 + b.test2 + b.test3)*2 AS Calc3,
             
            FROM Students a
            LEFT JOIN Group b on a.Name = b.Name
            LEFT JOIN Class c on  b.Name = c.Name
            WHERE a.Forte ('Math', 'PE')
            AND a.Hobby ('Eating', 'Video Games')
            GROUP BY a.Student_ID, a.birthday
                 ) subA
               GROUP BY Student_ID, BDate
```

Comment: If you had a database with trillions of rows, you wouldn't be asking for help on Stack Overflow. You'd be assigning the task to your team of Data Architecture Ph.D.'s, and then preparing a budget proposal in the ballpark of $100 million to run it.

Comment: Sorry! my bad. I'm just exaggerating. lets say millions

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). Or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get rid of the outer `SELECT`, just fold calc4 in.
- Get rid of Calc3; you don't use it.
- `INDEX(Student_ID, birthday)`  on `a`

I would hope that `b` and `c` have `PRIMARY KEY(name)`.  But, with a million rows, there *will be* duplicates.  So, I declare the question incomplete.